# regular expression - string replacement "as is"

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do this:

word `test` should be found in some text and be replaced with `<strong>test</strong>`. but the thing is, `Test` should be also catched and be replaced with `<strong>Test</strong>`.

I tried this:

```
word = "someword"
text = "Someword and many words with someword"
pattern = re.compile(word, re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.sub('<strong>'+word+'</strong>',text)
```

but in this case, `Someword` is becoming `someword`. Am I using `re` somehow wrong?

I want `<strong>Someword</strong> and many words with <strong>someword</strong>`

Comment: Be careful with HTML/XSS injection when doing this kind of substitution, `word` should either come from a trusted source (i.e. not user input) or it should have its contents escaped.

Comment: @LieRyan i have ``@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)`` decorator for it. does it help?

Comment: autoescape isn't going to help if you're going to insert this as safe text (which you must do if you don't want your `<strong>` tags to get escaped).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping):

```
>>> import re
>>> word = "someword"
>>> text = "Someword and many words with someword"
>>> pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % word, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> pattern.sub(r'<strong>\1</strong>',text)
'<strong>Someword</strong> and many words with <strong>someword</strong>'
```

Here `\1` refers to the first captured group, to what was captured inside the parenthesis.

Also see [Search and Replace](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) section of the python `re` module docs.

Comment: @doniyor glad to see it helped. Is it related to that problem with a chain of template filters you've described in comments in the other question today?

Comment: yes, more or less. but the chain problem isnot still solved. i am still on it :)

Comment: I don't know Python, but should that be `$1` instead of `\1`? Certainly in other languages `\1` works but is deprecated/discouraged. (This is not to be confused with the case of backreferences within the regex itself, in which case `\1` is required.)

Comment: @DavidKnipe, good point but it is working like a charm right now! :)

Comment: @alecxe Alex, the chain is working now somehow.. weird.. earlier it didnot because may be i needed some coffee.. ;).

Comment: @DavidKnipe python docs don't mention using `$` for referencing captured groups. `$` actually doesn't work. It looks like it is a regex implementation difference. I remember having a huge book describing differences in regex engines among popular languages, omg, there are so many pitfalls there. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe hey Alex, please let me know if you are here, i need small help

Comment: @doniyor okay, sure, if it's unrelated to the question, create a separate question or throw me a message on linkedin.

Comment: thanks man, the question is related to the one above. given ``some word``, i need that ``some`` as well as ``word`` are <stronged>-ed. with the code above, it is failing. I tried this: http://pastebin.com/UiQmyGkN

Comment: @doniyor you need to join words with `|`: `pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(esc(x) for x in sterm), re.IGNORECASE)`.